# Flutter doesn't compile project after restart

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

My computer restarted for no reason and now all settings in flutter running in vs code have changed. During restart, I got an option to verify the author or something. I believe to hit trust but after that, I can't compile my project anymore plus the default behavior of the mouse buttons has changed. Right-click now shows, change all occurrences instead of default options. My phone is connected but it doesn't show up in the emulator/phone section below.
The same project runs fine in android studio

[image: Flutter Issue]
[image: Flutter Extensions]

Comment: Check if your dart and flutter extensions are still there.

Comment: Your right click has lesser options because it did not identify the file type.

Comment: yes! the extensions are still there, however, the project runs fine in android studio. as you said the file type is not being identified for some reason I don't know.

Comment: Try removing .dart-tools, pubspec.lock, .packages and pub get again.

Comment: Did you have any run/debug configuration before? Are they present now?

Comment: None, I did try removing and adding extension but doesn't seem to work. As a last resort, I might have to reinstall everything. As you've mentioned VS-CODE doesn't find my installed extension of dart and flutter.

Comment: Weird Issue I should say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after reinstalling all my extensions, primarily dart and flutter a couple of times. Thank you @amsakanna

Answer (score 1):

1st run `flutter doctor` to check if there any problem with install.
try to clean the project using `flutter clean` and rebuil/ run again.

Also you can run from terminal,
you can just type on terminal `flutter run`  and it show devices then select one.

For emulators type `flutter emulators`  , it will show your emulators,
to run on emulators `flutter emulators --launch deviceName`.

here the short form.

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`
- `flutter run`

Comment: Thank you, will keep that in mind. For now, it seems to be like a loading error.